# Plotting a function in R with holding all variables constant except for one

Tags: r, ggplot2

How would I go about plotting a function holding one variable constant?

I would like to plot the "monthPay" about from the function below on y-axis and interest rate on the x-axis. All over variables would be held constant.

I believe there is a function to do this but I can't remember its name.

```
mortgage <- function(P=500000, I=6, L=30) { 
J <- I/(12 * 100)
N <- 12 * L
M <- P*J/(1-(1+J)^(-N))
monthPay <- M

# Calculate Amortization for each Month
    Pt <- P # current principal or amount of the loan
    currP <- NULL
    while(Pt>=0) {
        H <- Pt * J # this is the current monthly interest
        C <- M - H # this is your monthly payment minus your monthly interest, so it is the amount of principal you pay for that month
        Q <- Pt - C # this is the new balance of your principal of your loan
        Pt <- Q # sets P equal to Q and goes back to step 1. The loop continues until the value Q (and hence P) goes to zero
        currP <- c(currP, Pt)
    }#End Pt Calc

    monthP <- c(P, currP[1:(length(currP)-1)])-currP
    aDFmonth <<- data.frame(
                      Amortization=c(P, currP[1:(length(currP)-1)]), 
                      Monthly_Payment=monthP+c((monthPay-monthP)[1:(length(monthP)-1)],0),
                      Monthly_Principal=monthP, 
                      Monthly_Interest=c((monthPay-monthP)[1:(length(monthP)-1)],0), 
                      Year=sort(rep(1:ceiling(N/12), 12))[1:length(monthP)]
            )#end aDFmonth 
    aDFyear <- data.frame(
                     Amortization=tapply(aDFmonth$Amortization, aDFmonth$Year, max), 
                     Annual_Payment=tapply(aDFmonth$Monthly_Payment, aDFmonth$Year, sum), 
                     Annual_Principal=tapply(aDFmonth$Monthly_Principal, aDFmonth$Year, sum), 
                     Annual_Interest=tapply(aDFmonth$Monthly_Interest, aDFmonth$Year, sum), 
                     Year=as.vector(na.omit(unique(aDFmonth$Year)))
                     )#end aDFyear 

  return(list(monthPay, aDFmonth,aDFyear ))
}


temp<-mortgage(P=500000, I=6, L=30)
temp[[1]] #the var. for the y-axis.
```

Comment: try building a lot that is most of what you want, then post the code and graph so people know what you mean

Comment: I'm looking for a function such as 'cruve' which might work.  curve(mortgage(P=500000, L=30),  xname = "i")

Comment: You want something like `mortgage_vect_I <- Vectorize(function(i) {
  mortgage(P=500000, I = i, L=30)[[1]]
}, "i");
curve(mortgage_vect_I(x), from = 1, to = 10)`?

Comment: Is there a way to get ggplot to work. I tried: ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 10)), aes(x = x)) + stat_function(fun = function(x) (mortgage(P=500000, I = x, L=30)[[1]]), color = "red")